# Lua every 4 characters in string insert a value

Tags: lua

So I have a string that every 4 characters I need to insert a value like so.

```
local string = "24029400001000000000000000000000"
--insert : every 4 chars

--output
--2402:9400:0010:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
```

The output i am looking for is `2402:9400:0010:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000`

```
function string.chunk( str, n )
    local k, t
    t= { }
    for k in str:gmatch( string.rep( ".", n ) ) do
        table.insert( t, k )
    end
    return t
end

x = "24029400001000000000000000000000"
x_new = ""
for k, v in ipairs( x:chunk( 4 ) ) do
  v = v .. ":"
x_new = x_new .. v
end

print(x_new)

--problem is 2402:9400:0010:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000: the : on the end of string
```

Comment: What kind of code have you tried so far?

Comment: @Allister i edited my post to show you the code i am using right now there must be a smaller / easier way to accomplish what i am trying to do i also have a issue with a ":" on the end of my string.

Comment: You could do `table.concat(x:chunk( 4 ), ':')` instead of joining strings in loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solution:

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type="application/lua">

local s = "24029400001000000000000000000000"
s = s:gsub('....','%1:'):gsub(':$','')
print(s)

</script>
```

Comment: This is the best answer you're gonna get. It's been wrapped in script tags to provide you with a sandbox to execute it here but you can remove those. gsub('....','%1:') finds four characters and places a colon after them, which still leaves a trailing colon, so gsub(':$', '') finds a colon at the end of a string and removes it.